# Carry in a VHDL IF Statement Addition

Tags: vhdl

Just throwing this out there for VHDL gurus...

Suppose I have as declarations...

```
signal a: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

signal b: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
```

Now I have this IF statement...

```
if a > b + 2 then
```

What happens to the carry on the right half of the `IF` statement when `b` = 1110 or 1111? (Let's just say for my simulation there's a different result when the `b` declaration is `(3 downto 0)` vs `(4 downto 0)`.) And, for Xilinx Vivado synthesis, I'm assuming the synthesis would match the simulation results. Correct?

Comment: Without context of libraries, we cannot tell. Arithmatic is not possible with std_logic_vector without the use of another library. This could be numeric_std_unsigned from VHDL 2008 or the non-standard std_logic_signed or std_logic_unsigned. Which library is used would affect the result. Please post code with fill package use context.

Comment: The value b + 2 will be determined first. To include carry (or borrow) the left operand length can be be sign extended for a two's complement number (`"b'left" & b`) or length extended for an unsigned binary number (`"0" & b`). The right operand (2) is converted to the type of the left operand with a length of the left operand. The operand length is resized for ">" to the maximum of the L and R operands length. See the particular package sources. For numeric_std_unsigned you can length extend with the RESIZE function. Provide a [mcve]. All of Tricky's packages are synthesis eligible.